# Cant connect frontend and backend deployments in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have two k8s deployments in one cluster GKE, for one web application, one is frontend(react) and the other is backend(python), the frontend is working fine but when I try to do something on the frontend that calls the backend i got [this](https://prnt.sc/v8lvhj) , I have ingress for the frontend, which works perfectly, the only thing i can't figure it out is why the frontend can't reach the backend, i want them to communicate via services. I have the following services:

Frontend service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

Backend service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: backend
    track: stable
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
```

Any fix suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the frontend services? Is the frontend service a client side application running on a brower (like Angular)? Or is it another web application that runs on the server side, but that is failing to connect to the backend service deployed?

Comment: @lkamal it is a react application, that is the frontend, and the backend python, both are deployed on the same cluster, I was following this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) Both are deployed on GKE cluster using the GCP

Comment: I assume you are saying that this is a ReactJS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the applications are client side applications like react or Angular, the application runs on the client browser; not in the server side. In that case, the application in the client browser must invoke the APIs on the server (backend application).

In such a situation, even though the application is named backend; it must expose the APIs via the Ingress so that those APIs can be used by the frontend application running on the client browser.